# почему терминал выдает ошибку при запуске laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, openserver

Я новичок. Только начал работы с этим фрэймворком и пытаюсь созданный проект.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну видимо php никак не установлен?

Comment: Если php установлен, то нужно добавить php в переменную PATH. Мой компьютер -> Свойства -> Дополнительные параметры системы -> Переменные среды -> Path -> Изменить -> Создать -> Указать абсолютный пусть к папке с бинарником php

Comment: у опернсервера есть своя консоль с настроенным всем, ее и используейте. через контекстное меню в трее открывается. Собственно зачем serve запускать при наличии опенсервера тоже не ясно

Answer (score 0):

Если PHP установлен (скорее всего так и есть), то вероятно, необходимо указать путь до PHP. Для Linux это было бы примерно так: /usr/bin/php
Как это делается на OSPanel точно не вспомню, но принцип тот же. То есть система не может найти PHP интерпретатор и сообщает об этом.

Рекомендую вообще не использовать OSPanel, поскольку в дальнейшем также будут возникать "непонятные" ошибки - проверено на опыте))

Для Windows рекомендую начать использовать WSL2 и запускать Laravel в Docker. Как это сделать я уже писал инструкцию на своем блоге - https://vermutoff.com/laravel-docker-php-fpm-nginx-mysql.html

Есть и другие способы запускать Laravel в Docker. Например, в документации к Laravel есть инструкция запуска с помощью Laravel Sail, но мне этот подход не понравился.